# IOException: failed to connect to /192.168.70.1 (port 9900): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tags: java, android

When I am trying to run my android application in eclipse getting this exception:

```
IOException: failed to connect to /192.168.70.1 (port 9900): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the solution here:

Solution1: Make sure your windows firewall off.

Control Panel-->System and Security-->Windows Firewall-->Turn Windows Firewall on or off-->Turn Off Windows Firewall.

Solution2:

Go to CMD-->Right Click-->Run as Administrator-->Yes-->ipconfig-->Enter

[image]

Replace IP with IPv4 address..

Here the culprit is system 'IP' is went wrong. Please check IP of your system as a admin..

Note: Once check it, Some times the IP address also changes randomly.

May It helps to some one like me..

Thanks..

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here.

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\turn Windows Defender Firewall on or off\private network settings\Turn Off Windows Firewall.

its worked for me.

Comment: that is 99% of what the accepted answer describes as solution 1.

Comment: Great if you still using eclipse to run android app instead Android Studio ;P

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but I guess the better way is to open 9900 port on your firewall.
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Defender Firewall then choose Advanced Settings the create a rule for inbound and outbound for the port. That's all